# restangular POST request to flask server

Tags: flask, restangular

I'm trying to sens a POST request to a flask back-end. I'm using restangular with the following code:

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider){
   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://10.0.46.51:5000/patient');
   });

app.controller('inserisciCtrl', function($scope, Restangular){
$scope.formData={"first_name":"pierpaolo", "last_name":"croce"};
$scope.sendData=function sendData(){
  var paziente=Restangular.all('search');
  paziente.post($scope.formData);
}

});
```

But I get always this : "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405"
I think this is a CORS problem and I tryed to fix it following some others 
post..like:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-origin': '*'});
```

or

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']
```

but the problem remains.

Can someone help me in solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled POST on your Flask route?

```
@app.route('/patient', methods=['POST'])
```